# How can I mock a list of users in my redux actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I don't have my actual API developed yet, what would be a good way of returning a hard coded list of users in my json response?

My redux action looks like:

```
fetchUsers: (locationId) => {
  return dispatch => {
    let authToken = getItemFromStorage('authToken');      
    let url = API_ROOT + '/users/' + locationId + '?token=' + authToken;
    axios.get(url)
      .then(function(response) { 
        dispatch({
          type: Constants.USERS_RECEIVED,
          users: response.data.users,          
        });
      });
  };
```

Are there any good strategies of returning mock data while I develop my react frontend?

Comment: There's normally 3 bounded action creators - to throw the request, to process received data on success, to handle errors on failure. So, you may simply shortcircuit your above action creator to another action creator (the one you will use to process successfully received data) and assign your JSON data as a default parameter for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a pretty standard way of writing down an async action in Redux.

```js
export const fetchUser = authToken => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH_STARTS" });
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url), {
        headers: {
          Authorization: token
        }
      });
      dispatch({
        type: "AUTH_SUCCESS",
        data: { user: res.data.user }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: "AUTH_ERROR",
        data: { error: err }
      });
    }
  };
};
```

You have to handle all the cases, i.e., `FETCHING`, `FETCHING_SUCCESS`,`FETCHING_ERROR`

That's always considered a good practice.